# Inconsistent behaviour with Java reflection 'invoke' method

Tags: java, reflection

Please see these example classes.

A.java:

```
// A is not public
class A
{
    public static void foo()
    {

    }
}
```

B.java:

```
package p;

import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

public class B
{
    public void invoke() throws ClassNotFoundException, NoSuchMethodException, InvocationTargetException, IllegalAccessException
    {
        Class clazz = Class.forName("A");
        Method method = clazz.getDeclaredMethod("foo", new Class[0]);
        method.invoke(null, new Object[0]);
    }
}
```

C.java:

```
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;

public class C extends p.B
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, NoSuchMethodException, IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException
    {
        C c = new C();
        c.invoke();
    }

//  @Override
//  public void invoke() throws ClassNotFoundException, NoSuchMethodException, InvocationTargetException, IllegalAccessException
//  {
//      Class clazz = Class.forName("A");
//      Method method = clazz.getDeclaredMethod("foo", new Class[0]);
//      method.invoke(null, new Object[0]);
//  }
}
```

The 'invoke' method in main in C fails with:

IllegalAccessException: Class p.B can not access a member of class A with modifiers "public static"

If the 'invoke' method in C is exactly the same as the overriden method in p.B. However, if it is uncommented no Exception is being thrown.

Why the difference?

Comment: What package is class A in?  What package is class C in?

Answer (score 1):

Class `A` is package-private. Because `A` and `C` are in the same (default) package, it's a legal access to invoke `A.foo()` from any code in class `C`, but not in class `B`, which is in a different package.

If you override the method, `A.foo()` is invoked from within the same package. If you don't override the method, `A.foo()` is invoked from code in a different package, which is an illegal access.

You can replicate similar behavior just by adding the statement `A.foo()` in the respective `invoke()` methods. However, in this case you will get a compilation error instead of a run-time error.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. You're right about replicating it with calling A.foo(), so that behaviour is consistent.

What I don't like, is that invoke() is called on an object of class C, not an object of class B, it only inherits class B. So it should behave as one, allowing the call to package private A.

Other opinions?

Comment: it's just how polymorphism works, method is in class B so it does not matter what type of object it is exactly. If just extending some class would give access to everything in its package... then whole visibility thing would be just kinda useless.